# YouTube v3 API call for search.list: proper curl setting

Tags: php, api, curl, youtube-api

I am sending a call to the YouTube API using search.list (retrieve the first search result for a keyword) but I am getting nothing in return.

Here is my call:

```
$api_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&type=video&key=MYKEY&&format=json&q=SEARCHTERMS;
```

Note: MYKEY is my API key I got from Google (currently active) and SEARCHTERMS is any word to search.

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $data = json_decode($response);
    $value = json_decode(json_encode($data), true);
echo $value;
```

The URL works correctly (tested on browser) and I'm not getting any kind of error (console), but still this curl request isn't echoing any data from YouTube. Isn't it properly set?
P.s. My quota isn't exceeded.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!
Watch out: youtube API doesn't read spaces in url (eg. in search terms), so you gotta streplace all of them with "+"